Trying to send CAN message with Teensy 4.0 & CJMCU-2551
I'm trying to send CAN messages with a Teensy 4.0 & a CAN tranceiver CJMCU-2551.
I've connected as follow:

Teensy Pin 23 (TX1) → CJMCU-2551 TXD.
Teensy Pin 22 (RX1) → CJMCU-2551 RXD.
Teensy GND → CJMCU-2551 GND.
Teensy 3.3V (VCC) → CJMCU-2551 VCC. (EDIT: This was the mistake. It's hold be 5volt)
CJMCU-2551 CANH → CAN bus CANH on a VN1610
CJMCU-2551 CANL → CAN bus CANL on a VN1610

#include <FlexCAN_T4.h>  // Include the FlexCAN_T4 library for Teensy 4.0

// Define CAN bus object using CAN1
FlexCAN_T4<CAN1, RX_SIZE_256, TX_SIZE_16> CanBus;

// Define message parameters
const int ledPin = 13;  // Define LED pin for activity indicator
const uint32_t baudRate = 500000;  // CAN baud rate (500 kbps)
const uint32_t sendInterval = 500; // Interval to send messages (milliseconds)
CAN_message_t msg;  // Define CAN message object

void setup() {
  // Initialize serial communication for debugging
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize LED pin
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // Initialize CAN bus at 500 kbps
  CanBus.begin();
  CanBus.setBaudRate(baudRate);

  // Prepare CAN message
  msg.id = 0x123;           // Standard CAN ID
  msg.len = 8;              // Data length (8 bytes)
  msg.flags.extended = 0;   // Standard frame (11-bit identifier)
  msg.buf[0] = 0x11;        // Example data
  msg.buf[1] = 0x22;
  msg.buf[2] = 0x33;
  msg.buf[3] = 0x44;
  msg.buf[4] = 0x55;
  msg.buf[5] = 0x66;
  msg.buf[6] = 0x77;
  msg.buf[7] = 0x88;

  Serial.println("CAN bus initialized at 500 kbps.");
}

void loop() {
  // Send the CAN message
  CanBus.write(msg);

  // Print the message to Serial Monitor
  Serial.print("Sent CAN message ID: 0x");
  Serial.print(msg.id, HEX);
  Serial.print(" Data: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < msg.len; i++) {
    Serial.print(msg.buf[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Blink the LED to indicate activity
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(100);  // LED on for 100 ms
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(sendInterval - 100);  // Adjust delay to maintain 500 ms interval
}


The code does not through any fault but still I cant observer any message in CANalyzer.
Here is how my settings looks like in CANalyzer.
according to above

Solved. I did the dumb mistake of powering the CAN transceiver with 3.3V when it was suppose to be 5V.. the code above works fine.
